# Secure images failing - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My script pretty much works, however when I run a for loop it fails, in the view:

```
<?php foreach($pics as $index=>$pic){?>
            <td class='Pictures'>
                <center>

                <?php

                $piece = explode('/',$pic["ThumbImg"]);
                $string = $piece[5];



                ?>
                <img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Controller/getImage/<?php echo $string; ?>/1' width="100px"> 

                </a>
```

Controller class - Get image function:

```
//function to protect images from being accessed directly by obfuscating the URL
    function getImage($img_id,$type){

    if($this->members->logged_in()){    

          //code to authenticate user goes here then...

    //code to decide which type of file it is/thumb/full size image
    if($type==1)
    {
    $url = $this->data['base_url'].'system/application/images/pic/thumbs/';
    }else if($type==0){

    $url = $this->data['base_url'].'system/application/images/pic/';

    }

    $filepath = $url.$img_id;


    //send image to web browser.
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

      //get path
            $img_handle = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath) or die("");
       //create and send     
        ImageJpeg($img_handle);

    }
```

I suspect that this could be due to the headers being resent, if so how can I resolve this.

Cheers

Fixed the problem - used "Hotlinking"

Comment: so your code works when not in a loop? are you getting any errors? how do you know that its not working

Comment: Basically the web server gets stuck. And when it does finally execute the page, no images are fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You will basically only need to set the header information `header("Content-type: image/jpeg")` if you're loading the image from the database. But since you're loading it from a folder you might want to skip the php file and immediately fetch the image from the folder:

```
<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>img_folder/<?php echo $string; ?>/1' 
width="100px">
```

Comment: I can't do that. The whole point of fetching it via the controller is so that I can mask where the images are being fetched from. Doing it this way, will give away the original image path. Which defeats the whole point.